# "view width" property does not work correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I want to dynamically size my header text based upon the width of the screen. I also want to have a default minimum text size for small screens. To accomplish this feat, I used the following css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .welcome {
    font-size:30pt;
  }
  .welcome-subtitle {
    font-size:12pt;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .welcome {
    font-size:6vw;
  }
  .welcome-subtitle {
    font-size:1.8vw;
  }
}
```

And the following html

```
<h1 class="welcome"> <span style="font-weight:200;">Meet</span> <code class="text-nowrap">iSwiftUI</code> </h1>
```

Everything worked great. However, when I pushed the website some users reported that the header text size was unreadably small. It defaulted to our minimum text size. Screenshots of the intended behavior & the bug below.
[image: Properly Rendered Page]
[image: Improperly rendered page]

**EDIT:** Picture one was taken on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75. Picture two was taken on Chrome Version 85.0.4183.121.

Comment: what browser and screen size is it? I checked it on all screen sizes, seems fine to me. Is it an old browser version. 
IE 10+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 34+, Safari 7+, Android 4.4+, iOS 6+ – Supported. 

Chrome 20-34, Safari 6 – Supported but has repaint issue

Comment: Hey good question. I added version numbers to the post. Both were on chrome.